# A list of tuples in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, list

I am trying to basically do the equivalent of this in VBA:

```
myArray.apend((field1, field2, field3))
```

(using Python syntax)

So something where each element of the array/list has three elements. Can this be done in VBA?

Comment: You can have arrays within arrays, if that is what you mean. Something like `myArray = Array(Array(field1, field2, field3), Array(...), ..., )`

Comment: I want the ability to add them dynamically, not just statically all in one line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To extend an array, use the `ReDim` statement:

```
Sub foo()
'## Declares your array of len==1
ReDim myArray(0)
myArray(0) = Array("A","B","C")
'## Extends your array:
ReDim Preserve myArray(Ubound(myArray)+1)
myArray(Ubound(myArray)) = Array("item1", "item2", "item3")

End Sub
```

Of course, since the item you've added is also an array, you could use the `ReDim Preserve` on the individual array items, as per cyboashu's answer, but this may be somewhat tedious/redundant.

```
Dim chld
i = UBound(myArray)
'Get a handle on the child array
chld = myArray(i)
'Extend it using ReDim Preserve
ReDim Preserve chld(UBound(chld) + 1)
'Add another value to the new item:
chld(UBound(chld)) = "another value"
'Reassign back to the parent array
myArray(i) = chld
```

You could also use the `System.Collections.ArrayList` object:

```
Sub f()

Dim myArrayList As Object
Dim i As Long

Set myArrayList = ArrayList

'Add ArrayList child objects to the ArrayList object:
myArrayList.Add ArrayList
i = myArrayList.Count - 1
'Add items to the child ArrayList:
myArrayList.Item(i).Add "A"
myArrayList.Item(i).Add "B"
myArrayList.Item(i).Add "C"

'Add some more:
myArrayList.Add ArrayList
i = myArrayList.Count - 1
myArrayList.Item(i).Add 1
myArrayList.Item(i).Add 2
myArrayList.Item(i).Add 3

'Dump this in to a VBA Array, if needed:
Dim myArray
myArray = myArrayList.ToArray()

End Sub
Function ArrayList()
    Set ArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Function
```

Screenshot of the `.ToArray` output in the Locals window:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jagged Arrays:

Example:

```
Sub jaggedArray()


    Dim arrMaster()
    Dim arrChild()

    Dim lCtr        As Long
    Dim lCtr2       As Long

    For lCtr = 1 To 5
        ReDim Preserve arrMaster(1 To lCtr)
        For lCtr2 = 1 To 3
          ReDim Preserve arrChild(1 To lCtr2)

          arrChild(lCtr2) = "Child " & lCtr2

          '/ Assing array in to array
          arrMaster(lCtr) = arrChild

        Next
    Next


End Sub
```